# Relative Layout: Buttons (Android)

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

by setting four Buttons on a XML. I try this in the RelativeLayout, and for Galaxy Nexus 4 in the Graphicsl View it looks good, but when i change to another VIew like the Nexus 10 it looks horrible.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.b2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then what you want to do?

Comment: `looks horrible` in what sense? How does it look like? maybe add screenshot

Comment: provide diff layout for diff android screen will solve your pbm such as sw600dp,sw720dp for 7 inch and 10 inch tablet

Comment: What is it that you want us to do?

Comment: https://lh4.ggpht.com/Efan4AxQ79QfZC5zC7-HmsH1PqmazxYA0aDniXBers0oU3fo2z86dusGAb8LkeXAEGg=h900-rw             It should look like this!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbutton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
           />

</LinearLayout>  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttdtgyodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttrtodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the above will show all button in same line what ever the size it will never metter

Comment: you can use it by 2... 2 in 1 layout and another 2 in another.. if find problem in implementing then ask

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttdtgyodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put them in 1 rel layout and another 2 in another rel layout

Comment: I've tried your code-example, but i want my layout should look like this: https://lh4.ggpht.com/Efan4AxQ79QfZC5zC7-HmsH1PqmazxYA0aDniXBers0oU3fo2z86dusGAb8LkeXAEGg=h900-rw

Answer (score 0):

use LinearLayout and **android:layout_weight="size".**